Taylor expansion of the function $f(x)=(1+x) ^ {1/x}$ in $x = 0$, to the second order
I there, I have to compute the taylor expansion of this function:
$$f(x) = (1+x)^{1/x}$$
in $x = 0$, to the second order.
First I have transformed the function:
$$(1+x)^{1/x} = e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}$$
then I expandend the log:
$$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = \frac{x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}}{x}=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}$$
then
$$(1+x)^{1/x} = e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}} = e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}} = e\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}}$$
expanding the exponential function to the first order I obtained:
$$e\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}}=e\left(1+\left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}\right)\right)
=e\left(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}\right)$$
I omitted the little-o computation.
Unfortunately the correct result is
$$e\cdot\left(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{11x^2}{24}\right)$$
why is the second order term wrong?

Hint:$$\exp\left(-\frac12x+\frac13x^2\right)=1+\left(-\frac12x+\frac13x^2\right)+\frac12\left(-\frac12x+\frac13x^2\right)^2+\cdots$$includes how many sources of an $x^2$ term?

ah...I was convinced that it was enough to expand to the first order if this eventually results in the second order...so I have to take every second order term...it makes sense, thanks

As point out by J.G.' comment, you have to consider all the terms that have $x^2$:
\begin{align}\exp\left(1-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}3\right)&\sim e\exp\left(-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}3\right)\sim e\left(1-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}3+\frac12\left(-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}3\right)^2\right)\\& \sim e\left(1-\frac x2+\frac{11}{24}x^2\right) \end{align}
